# API search filtering bug

Tags: search, soundcloud

There is a problem with the API track filtering:

This returns a JSON:

[https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=electonica&duration[from]=0&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=electonica&duration%5Bfrom%5D=0&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg)

And removing the zero from the duration it only returns an [] empty array
[https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=electonica&duration[from]=&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=electonica&duration%5Bfrom%5D=&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg)

The bigger issue is that these parameters also doesn't work and they should return results. I expect tracks (mixes in fact) longer than 25 minutes. 
[http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=lounge&created_at[from]=2012-04-01%2023:29:12&duration[from]=1500000&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?offset=0&filter=public,streamable&tags=lounge&created_at%5Bfrom%5D=2012-04-01%2023:29:12&duration%5Bfrom%5D=1500000&order_by=hotness&consumer_key=ZbOZAiYTx8wbuIaqRhfubg)

Comment: Is there anyone from SoundCloud here to comment on this issue?

Comment: hi Tibor, I'll raise this with the appropriate team and hopefully get an answer for you soon.

Comment: Thanks. If you need any additional info let me know.